# Natural Deduction Fitch-style Proof

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Find the Fitch Style Proof for the following argument:

$((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow A) \rightarrow A)$

I am quite unsure on how to apply the famous rules of natural deduction. Would welcome any comprehensive proofs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin at from the ground level

We should prove $((A\to B)\to A)\to A$ by deriving $A$ under assumption of $(A\to B)\to A$ to introduce the conditional .  It: a Conditional Proof .

$$\def\fitch#1#2{~~~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\fitch{}{\fitch{(A\to B)\to A}{~~\vdots\\A}\\((A\to B)\to A)\to A}$$

Now, we might be able to derive $A$ under that assumption if we could derive $A\to B$, but *there is no way to do that*.   Therefore we can only prove $A$ under that assumption by deriving a contradiction under the further assumption of $\neg A$.  Ie: a Proof by Reduction to Absurdity.

$$\fitch{}{\fitch{(A\to B)\to A}{\fitch{\neg A}{~~\vdots\\~\bot}\\\neg\neg A\\A}\\((A\to B)\to A)\to A}$$

Okay, well, that contradiction can only be of one of the assumptions; and as before, we might derive $A$ if we could derive $A\to B$, and now *we can do so*.

$$\fitch{}{\fitch{(A\to B)\to A}{\fitch{\neg A}{~~\vdots\\A\to B\\A\\~\bot}\\\neg\neg A\\A}\\((A\to B)\to A)\to A}$$

So how might *you* derive $A\to B$ in the context of those assumptions?

Comment: I think it should "two assumptions" at the end, right? First is $(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow A$ and second is Negation $A$

Comment: And also, if you have negation $A$, then using modus tollens would imply that "$\textbf{negation}$ of $(A \rightarrow B)"$ is true, not "$(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow A$".

Comment: Yes. So do *not* use *modus tolens*.  You can use *modus ponens* to derive $A$ from $(A\to B)\to A$ and $A\to B$.  So how can you first derive $A\to B$?